# wso2 esb - skip dbreport mediator when DB connection failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I created a datasource for dbreport mediator to log into MSSQL database. i want to skip this mediator when database connection failure occurs. I have used "Validation Query" in datasource, but it doesn't solve the problem. 
When a database connection exception occurs, fault sequence executes.
Is there any solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is to put the DBreport mediator and associated code into a seperate sequence. You can then set a faultsequence for that specific situation. Where you handle the connection exception and continue as normal.

This way you create what resembles a try/catch construction. For more on that you can also check this [blog](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/10/wso2-esb-examples-best-practises-error-handling-wso2-esb/).

Another option is to use the [clone mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Clone+Mediator), and have one sequence continue the message as usual while the other sequence tries write to the database and stops after that. This is based on the assumption that the the database write is not critical, and it should not influence the rest of the message flow even when it fails.